# Convert array element to float

Tags: python, pandas

I have a one dimensional array called monteCarloPerf which can look something like:

```
monteCarloPerf  [[113.4848779294831], [169.65800173373898], [211.35999049731927], [169.65800173373901], [229.66974328119005]]
```

I am retrieving a single element from the array using:

```
finalValue = monteCarloPerf[arrayValue]
```

where arrayValue is an integer.

Say arrayValue = 0, at the moment I am getting returned : [113.4848779294831].  Is there a way to just return the float without the brackets please? So I would be returned just 113.4848779294831.

Many thanks

Comment: moteCarloPerf[arrayValue][0]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your object `monteCarloPerf` is a one dimensional array containing elements of one dimensional arrays, or a list of lists. In order to access the value of the first element of the object you have to change your access to that element to the following:

```
finalValue = monteCarloPerf[arrayValue][0]
```

Answer (score 1):

In fact, that is a 'TWO dimensional' array.

To get the float value you can do the following:

```
finalValue = monteCarloPerf[arrayValue][0]
```

Or you can transform the two dimensional array to a one dimensional array:

```
one_dim = [item[0] for item in monteCarloPerf]
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

`monteCarloPerf` is a list of list. When you are using `monteCarloPerf[index]` it is returning list at `index` position. Based on the symmetry in your list, in each sub-list, item at `[0]` position is the actual value you are trying to fetch.

Use this to fetch the value

```
finalValue = monteCarloPerf[arrayValue][0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a weird way to do this without using `list.__getitem__()` method:

`float(''.join(i for i in str(monteCarloPerf[arrayValue])))`